# wxPythonを使用した画像とテキストの並び方について

Tags: python, python3

開発・テストはMacでしています

以下のような配置を考えています
横位置でセンタリングもします

テキスト
テキスト 画像

イメージですと
　　商品名
値段 円記号の画像

ベースをwx.VERTICALにし、値段のところをwx.HORIZONTALにすれば良いかと考え以下のコードにしました

```
self._notebook = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY)
self._goods_item_panel = wx.Panel(self._notebook, wx.ID_ANY)

name = wx.StaticText(self._goods_item_panel, -1, goods['name'], style=wx.TE_CENTER)
price = wx.StaticText(self._goods_item_panel, -1, str(goods['price']), style=wx.TE_CENTER)

layout = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
layout.Add(bitmap, flag=wx.GROW)
layout.Add(name, flag=wx.GROW)

image = wx.Image('./a.png')
bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self._goods_item_panel, -1, image, size=(image.GetSize()), style=wx.CENTER)
layout2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
layout2.Add(bitmap, flag=wx.GROW)
layout2.Add(price, 0)
layout.Add(layout2)
```

商品名はセンタリング出来るのですが、値段のところが左寄せから変えることが出来ません

アドバイスでもいただけると助かります

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`layout.Add(layout2, 1, flag=wx.CENTER)`と記述してlayout2を中央寄せで配置するのはいかがでしょうか。

```
import wx

application = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, u'テスト', size=(300, 200))

notebook = wx.Notebook(frame, wx.ID_ANY)
goods_item_panel = wx.Panel(notebook, wx.ID_ANY)

goods = {'name' : u'うまい棒', 'price': 10 }

name = wx.StaticText(goods_item_panel, -1, goods['name'], style=wx.TE_CENTER)
price = wx.StaticText(goods_item_panel, -1, str(goods['price']), style=wx.TE_CENTER)
layout = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
#layout2に配置するためコメントアウト layout.Add(bitmap, flag=wx.GROW)
layout.Add(name, flag=wx.GROW)

image = wx.Bitmap('a.jpg')
bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(goods_item_panel, -1, image, size=(image.GetSize()), style=wx.CENTER)

layout2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
layout2.Add(price, 0, flag=wx.TOP) #priceとbitmapのflagを一致させないと縦位置がずれる
layout2.Add(bitmap, 1, flag=wx.TOP)
layout.Add(layout2, 1, flag=wx.CENTER) #layout2自体を中央寄せ

goods_item_panel.SetSizer(layout)
notebook.AddPage(goods_item_panel, u'商品')

frame.Show()
notebook.Refresh()
application.MainLoop()
```

Comment: 期待の状態になりました。ありがとうございます。